# Space Below <iframe> in Flask with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I'm trying to embed a podcast into my flask website, and I'd I'm using bootstrap. When I embed using bootstrap. This is the code for the embed:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1" style="display:block;">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://anchor.fm/torasimecha/embed/episodes/Braishis---Imperfect-is-Very-Good-ekuhka" 
  </iframe>
</div>
```

It loads fine and adjusts based on the size of the window, which is what I want, but it also includes a lot of space below the actual content that pushes the rest of the content on my website down.

This is the link I'm embedding.
Is there a way to get rid of the space below the actual content in the ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `scrolling="no"` to disable scrolling like this:

```html
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1" style="display:block;">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" scrolling="no" src="https://anchor.fm/torasimecha/embed/episodes/Braishis---Imperfect-is-Very-Good-ekuhka" 
  </iframe>
</div>
```

You can also set the `height` property to get rid of all the extra space:

```html
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1" style="display:block;">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" scrolling="no" height="100" src="https://anchor.fm/torasimecha/embed/episodes/Braishis---Imperfect-is-Very-Good-ekuhka" 
  </iframe>
</div>
```